# Proving that $Df(\vec{0})=\vec 0$ for differentiable and even function $f : \mathbb{R}^n\to \mathbb{R}$

Tags: multivariable-calculus, differential-geometry, derivatives

Let $f : \mathbb{R}^n\to \mathbb{R}$ a function so that $f(\vec x)=f(-\vec{x})$ for all $\vec x\in \mathbb{R}^n$ ($f$ is even function). If $f$ is differentiable in all point $\vec x_0\in\mathbb{R}^n$. Calcule $Df(\vec{0})$.

I know that $Df(\vec{0})=\vec 0\in \mathbb{R}^n$, now, then

$$\lim_{\vec x\to \vec 0}\frac{f(\vec x)-f(\vec 0)-Df(\vec 0)\vec x}{\|\vec x\|}=\lim_{\vec x\to \vec 0}\frac{f(\vec x)-f(\vec 0)}{\|\vec x\|}$$

My quiestion is, how to prove that the previous limit on the right is zero?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: The symmetry of $f$ around $0$ as well as the continuity around $0$ implies that $f$ is constant, or otherwise has a local extrema at $0$. Can you prove this? If so, the result follows immediately.

Comment: HINT:  $$\left.\frac{\partial f(\vec x)}{\partial x_i}\right|_{\vec x=\vec 0}\equiv\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{f(\hat x_ih)-f(\vec 0)}{h}=\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{f(\vec 0)-f(-\hat x_ih)}{h}$$Now exploit the even symmetry and ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Either* use the chain rule and the equation $f(\vec x)=f(-\vec x)$ to deduce that $Df(\vec x) = -Df(\vec x)$ ... *or* reason as follows:
$$f(\vec x)-f(\vec 0) = Df(\vec 0)\vec x + \epsilon(\vec x)\|\vec x\|,$$
where $\epsilon(\vec x)\to 0$ as $\vec x\to\vec 0$. Therefore, since $f(\vec x)=f(-\vec x)$, we have
$$Df(\vec 0)\vec x - Df(\vec 0)(-\vec x) = \big(\epsilon(\vec x)-\epsilon(-\vec x)\big)\|\vec x\|;$$
from this you can easily conclude that $Df(\vec 0) = 0$.